# Identity Provider-Initiated Single Sign-On - get user informaion

Tags: asp.net-core, saml-2.0

I have a web application. Currently we have a portal that authenticates the user and then redirects to our webpage. I know the issues with identity provider initiated single sign on, however this is the path the site owner wishes to go.

The site is successfully authenticating the user, and redirecting to my ASP.net core application. However I cannot seem to get any of the authentication data. I have checked contacts.user.claims as well as security principal all appear to be null. I do know sample information is being returned in the request by using the Google tool saml tracer.

I am looking for any samples retrieving the sample information from my application after it has been redirected from a identity provider.

In the end I am trying to get the userid once the identity provider sent to me.

Thank you for any assistance or suggestions.

Comment: What's the identity provider?

Comment: IBM security access manager